# How to remove certain fields in a WTForms child class?

Tags: python, wtforms

I understand that it's possible to add fields in a child Form by doing something like:

```
class MyMainForm(Form):
    name = StringField()
    age = IntegerField()

class MyChildForm(MyMainForm):
    salary = FloatField()
```

but how do I remove the field 'age' from the child form? (thus getting a value of None in the 'age' attribute of the populated object). Of course this is a simplified example and I'm dealing with tens of fields in my actual classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't `MyChildForm` to really be a child of `MyMainForm`, then it shouldn't be. You should restructure your classes.

```
class ParentForm(Form):
    name = StringField()

class ChildFormAge(ParentForm):
    age = IntegerField()

class ChildFormSalary(ParentForm):
    salary = FloatField()
```

Comment: Thanks..that makes sense. I was hoping to use some WTForms automagic like:
    class MyChildForm(MyMainForm):
        exclude_fields = ('age',)
        salary = FloatField()
 
So that the field 'age' would not be 'rendered' by default for the form (but still be available as a field of the Form class for direct access). But I realize that this might be an overkill to have been implemented inside WTForms, and is best handled in client code, either by creating the inheritance carefully (like you suggest), or overriding __iter__ for the form or something..